# Как исправить толстую модель для загрузки?

Tags: php, yii, кодировка

Использую рецепт http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/form.file.upload.fat.model.
Проблема в том, что при обновлении имени (не документа), удаляется ссылка на документ (сам документ на месте). Я понимаю, что приходит пустой пост, но как это поправить?

И еще, при сохранении русского документа, сохранение идет в кракозябре. Потом оно нормально отображается, но в папке кракозябры. Я понимаю, что он win 1251 пережимает в unicode, но все же неприятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

толстая модель оказалась нежизнеспособной

реализовал так http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/07/yii.html